# How to pass v-avatar to chips children of multiselect v-select?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

I achieved with this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label class="form-label">{{ label }}</label>
    <v-select
      v-model="selecteds"
      item-title="user_name"
      item-value="id"
      :items="items"
      multiple
    >
      <template #selection="data">
        <v-chip
          :key="data.item.id"
          closable
          :model-value="data.selected"
          :disabled="data.deleted_at"
        >
          <template #prepend>
            <v-avatar size="32" image="https://i.pravatar.cc/64" />
          </template>
          {{ data.item.title }}
        </v-chip>
      </template>
    </v-select>

    <input
      v-for="selected in selecteds"
      :key="selected.id"
      type="hidden"
      :name="label + '[]'"
      :value="selected.id"
    >
  </div>
</template>
```

But this implementation have two problems. When I close one chip, the v-select opens. And the chip item doesnt get removed from the selected items of v-select.

I also tried this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label class="form-label">{{ label }}</label>
    <v-select
      v-model="selecteds"
      item-title="user_name"
      item-value="id"
      :items="items"
      chips
      closable-chips
      multiple
    >
      <template v-slot:prepend>
        <v-avatar size="32" image="https://i.pravatar.cc/64" />
      </template>
    </v-select>

    <input
      v-for="selected in selecteds"
      :key="selected.id"
      type="hidden"
      :name="label + '[]'"
      :value="selected.id"
    >
  </div>
</template>
```

This implementation works as expected, but the avatar doesnt get into the prepend slot of the chip, but the v-select. I would like the avatars to be in the chip. Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell if its intentional with Vuetify 3 or that it actually needs work because its so poorly documented and there are no examples out there however I get this to work by omitting the chip props on the select component and implement the chip with a slot.

```
<v-select
    v-model="items"
    :items="config"  
    item-title="name"
    item-value="name"                                         
    label="Select"
    multiple
    return-object            
>
    <template v-slot:selection="{ item, index, props }">               
        <v-chip closable :prepend-avatar="item.raw.img" v-bind="props" @click:close="update(index)">{{item.raw.name}}</v-chip>   
    </template>
    <template v-slot:item="{ item, props }">
        <v-list-item :prepend-avatar="item.raw.img" v-bind="props"></v-list-item>
    </template>
</v-select>
```

Example: https://codepen.io/alexpetergill/pen/wvEYyNw